# Why is the first part of my concatenated string diappearing in ESP32 with C++?

Tags: c++, esp32

I am creating a project with an ESP32 with PlatformIO. I have this function (which I simplify for the purpose of the question):

```cpp
void request_tts(string text) {
  string body = "{\"text\":\"" + text + "\", \"voice_name\":\"es-US-Neural2-B\"}";

  Serial.println(body.c_str());
  Serial.println(ESP.getFreeHeap());
}
```

And the output is:

```
", "voice_name":"es-US-Neural2-B"}
221672
```

I have tried several ways of concatenating the string, but it just won't work, for some reason. The `Serial.println(ESP.getFreeHeap());` is to check if I have free space for it, which I clearly do. I have also tried using `.append()`, using a `const char *` and `strcat()` (this got an error saying that it would overflow), and even using Arduino's `String`. Nothing worked. I asked ChatGPT, and it said that I wasn't double quoting correctly the `text` variable, which sounds impossible.

Two days ago this worked perfectly, what happened?

Comment: My guess would be that `text` ends with a carriage return. Please show a [mre]

Comment: *Nothing worked. I asked ChatGPT* -- You could have printed out the integer value of each of those characters and see if there are any control characters in the string.   ChatGPT is no replacement for simple in-depth debugging.

Comment: ChatGPT doesn't know anything about anything; it's [Clever Hans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clever_Hans) made out of silicon.

Comment: Send the output to `program | xxd -g 1` to view it as hex.

Comment: What I'm fearing, and starting to see more and more on StackOverflow, are attempts of using ChatGPT to do basic debugging, such as I mentioned in the previous comment.   Something that takes mere minutes to set up, now is being wasted trying to get AI to figure out their program, and usually sending the programmer down the wrong path.

Comment: I was just saying that I _even_ looked in ChatGPT. I just thought that it could be something basic about the language that I didn't know. That's all. I wasn't expecting any complex solution.

Comment: It was indeed a carriage return. thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

IIRC `string` concatenation doesn't work if the first element is a C-style string (i.e. a pointer to `char` array). That's because you can't concatenate pointers to C strings with a `+` operator - that just does arithmetic on the pointers.

However, if you convert the first element into a `string`, then its concatenation is activated by `+`:

```
string body = string("{\"text\":\"") + text + "\", \"voice_name\":\"es-US-Neural2-B\"}";
```